# XPath Expression to get element after an other

Tags: java, xpath, jwebunit

I have following structure:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Index of /</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Index of /</h1>
    <pre>
        <img src="/icons/blank.gif" alt="Icon "> <a href="?C=N;O=D">Name</a>                    <a
            href="?C=M;O=A">Last modified</a>      <a href="?C=S;O=A">Size</a>  <a
            href="?C=D;O=A">Description</a>
        <hr>
        <img src="/icons/folder.gif" alt="[DIR]"> <a href="berta.ear/">berta.ear/</a>          23-Sep-2014 13:17    -   
        <img src="/icons/folder.gif" alt="[DIR]"> <a href="egon.ear/">egon.ear/</a>          24-Oct-2014 16:04    -   
        <img src="/icons/folder.gif" alt="[DIR]"> <a href="anton01.ear/">anton01.ear/</a>             18-Dec-2014 12:03    -   
        <img src="/icons/folder.gif" alt="[DIR]"> <a href="anton02.ear/">anton02.ear/</a>             18-Dec-2014 08:38    -   
        <img src="/icons/folder.gif" alt="[DIR]"> <a href="anton03.ear/">anton03.ear/</a>             18-Dec-2014 11:43    -   
        <img src="/icons/folder.gif" alt="[DIR]"> <a href="anton04.ear/">anton04.ear/</a>             05-Dec-2014 16:02    -   
        <img src="/icons/folder.gif" alt="[DIR]"> <a href="anton05.ear/">anton05.ear/</a>             15-Sep-2014 19:22    -   
        <img src="/icons/folder.gif" alt="[DIR]"> <a href="anton06.ear/">anton06.ear/</a>             17-Dec-2014 10:50    -   
        <img src="/icons/folder.gif" alt="[DIR]"> <a href="anton07.ear/">anton07.ear/</a>             10-Dec-2014 13:02    -   
        <img src="/icons/folder.gif" alt="[DIR]"> <a href="anton08.ear/">anton08.ear/</a>             15-Dec-2014 09:30    -   
        <img src="/icons/folder.gif" alt="[DIR]"> <a href="anton09.ear/">anton09.ear/</a>             18-Dec-2014 08:47    -   
        <img src="/icons/folder.gif" alt="[DIR]"> <a href="anton10.ear/">anton10.ear/</a>             18-Dec-2014 11:11    -   
        ....
        </pre>
```

So now i'm trying to get the information of the `<a href=...` but only for those which are following a `<img src=".." alt="[DIR]">...`

So i have created an XPath which looks like this:

```java
tester.getElementsByXPath("/html/body/pre/*[self::img[@alt='[DIR]']]");
```

The above will only give me the `<img ...>` elements. But what i need are the `<a href=""..>` elements.

Anyone a idea what i'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get next `a` siblings using `following-sibling` selector:

```
/html/body/pre/*[self::img[@alt='[DIR]']]/following-sibling::a
```

Answer (score 1):

After tidying up the HTML so that it can be parsed as XML, and assuming that the `<img>` tags are self closed (viz don't wrap the a's), this xpath should find any a, with a previous sibling which is both an `img`, and has an `alt='[DIR]'` attribute:

```
/html//a[(preceding-sibling::img[1])[1][local-name()='img' and @alt='[DIR]']]
```

Comment: I would like to give both an accept..but i can only give a single. Both solutions work. Tidying up is not possible cause the output is automaticially created by a configured http server (Apache).